# How to create a Pathway Enrichment heatmap in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, ggpubr

I have some data like below:

[image]

```
dput(Int)

structure(list(ID = c("GO", "GO", "GO", "Kegg", "Reactome", "Reactome", 
"GO", "GO", "GO", "GO", "Reactome", "GO", "Reactome", "GO", "Kegg", 
"Kegg"), Description = c("regulation of developmental growth", 
"cell maturation", "cell-substrate adhesion", "MAPK signaling pathway", 
"MET activates PTK2 signaling", "Signaling by MET", "growth factor binding", 
"canonical Wnt signaling pathway", "regulation of cellular response to growth factor stimulus", 
"regulation of cell cycle G2/M phase transition", "Glycolysis", 
"cell cycle DNA replication", "Signaling by EGFR", "stem cell differentiation", 
"Ras signaling pathway", "Calcium signaling pathway"), GeneRatio = c("6/62", 
"4/62", "26/224", "15/136", "8/144", "8/144", "13/220", "10/151", 
"14/151", "10/332", "33/2605", "26/3798", "20/2605", "7/62", 
"15/213", "15/213"), BgRatio = c("347/18670", "177/18670", "354/18670", 
"438/10971", "30/10654", "79/10654", "137/17696", "335/18670", 
"292/18670", "213/18670", "71/10654", "71/18670", "49/10654", 
"257/18670", "337/10971", "288/10971"), pvalue = c(0.001010736, 
0.002839063, 1.57e-13, 0.000338402, 4.17e-09, 1.06e-05, 1.64e-08, 
0.000406096, 1.11e-07, 0.004942, 4.17e-05, 0.001096187, 0.008292794, 
2.23e-05, 0.002389972, 0.00049388), p.adjust = c(0.031471355, 
0.047398143, 4.9e-11, 0.00342914, 9.91e-08, 0.00018386, 8.97e-07, 
0.034667052, 0.000278314, 0.038642228, 0.000242305, 0.011469503, 
0.029134446, 0.015875363, 0.03632758, 0.015479437), qvalue = c(0.024333169, 
0.036647518, 3.88e-11, 0.002920943, 8.26e-08, 0.000153301, 7.72e-07, 
0.030920283, 0.000248234, 0.030524074, 0.000156277, 0.0094808, 
0.018790567, 0.012274587, 0.029015103, 0.012363539), Count = c(6L, 
4L, 26L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 10L, 14L, 10L, 33L, 26L, 20L, 7L, 
15L, 15L), Subtypes = c("GroupA", "GroupA", "GroupB", "GroupB", 
"GroupB", "GroupB", "GroupB", "GroupB", "GroupB", "GroupB", "GroupB", 
"GroupB", "GroupB", "GroupC", "GroupC", "GroupC"), Cluster = c("Cluster1", 
"Cluster1", "Cluster2", "Cluster2", "Cluster2", "Cluster2", "Cluster2", 
"Cluster3", "Cluster3", "Cluster3", "Cluster4", "Cluster4", "Cluster4", 
"Cluster1", "Cluster5", "Cluster5")), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

I created a dot plot with following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

Int2 <- Int[order(Int$Cluster, decreasing = FALSE),]
Int2$Description <- factor(Int2$Description, levels=Int2$Description[order(Int2$Cluster)])

p <- ggplot(Int2, aes(x = Count, y = Description)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = Count, color = p.adjust)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15, face = "bold", color = "black"),
        axis.title=element_text(size=15, face = "bold", color = "black")) +
  scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(0, 0.10), low="red") +
  ylab(NULL)

p1 <- p + facet_grid(.~Subtypes, scale = "free") +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black", face = "bold"))
```

But I'm interested in creating a pathway enrichment heatmap showing pathways on y-axis and clusters on the top and also showing subtypes on right side of the figure.

It should some how look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may get you closer to what you are looking for, but I wonder if something like the {gt} package might be easier to get things more into a table format...

```
axis_text_colors <- case_when(Int2$ID == "GO" ~ "blue", 
                              Int2$ID == "Kegg" ~ "purple", 
                              Int2$ID == "Reactome" ~ "green")

ggplot(Int2) + 
  aes(x = Cluster, y = Description) + 
  facet_grid(Subtypes ~ ., space = "free_y", scale = "free_y") +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = p.adjust)) +
  # scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(0, 0.10), low="red") +
  labs(
    x = NULL, 
    y = NULL
  ) + 
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), 
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = axis_text_colors)
  ) +
  NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made the necessary changes to the code and it looks as I want.